# Scala JSON Nesting

Tags: scala

Right now I have a bunch of JSON objects that are stored in a map. I want to nest them into one larger JSON object. I've been writing a function to do that but need help on how to nest JSON in Scala?

My function looks like this:

```
  def jsonClob(json:Map[Int, jsonClass]): Any = {
    var nestedJson = mutable?
    for(i<-json){
      val clobber = i._2
      val fieldName = clobber.getDatasetFieldName
      val jsonO = clobber.getJsonObject
    }
  }
```

I am not sure what my var mutable object should be? I have a loop that will grab each object out of the map from my custom Json Class, use a getDatasetFieldName which will be the higher level in the nesting, than get the entire object. My goal is to next each jsonObject based on the fieldName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will give you a `Map` of `(getDatasetFieldName, getJsonObject)`

```
json.map{case (x,y)=> y.getDatasetFieldName-> y.getJsonObject}
```

Convert `Map` to json using the library you are using.

Comment: Curious if you've seen this before: {"sizeMapDefined":false,"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true} when I pass each individual object its fine but now when I go to a immutable map I get {"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. If unrelated you could ask a new question?